# Convert a text file to a sql file

Tags: java

I am working on an assignment that open a text file and convert/save as sql file. I got how to open a text file but I am stuck on how to convert to sql file.

Here is code that I got for reading the text file

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // The path to open the file.
        String fileName = "input.txt";
        String line = null;

        try {
            // The file reads text files 
            FileReader file = new FileReader(fileName);

            // Wrap file in BufferedReader
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(file);

            while ( (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            // Close files
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch ( FileNotFoundException ex ) {
            System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'");
        } catch ( IOException ex ) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Can you anybody give me some hint how to save a text file as sql file after reading the text file?

Thank you so much!

Comment: just replace `|` with `,` in each line.

Comment: @Satya thank you, but there is nothing wrong with reading the text file, the output still show the '|'. I am stuck on how to convert the text file into sql file as the sample output given above

Comment: `|` is a special char in regular expression. Use like `//|`.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your try block like below.
There are two functions added `List<String> parseLine(String line)` and `String createInsert(List<String> headers, List<String> rowData)`

Implement the first using simple String tokenization and then createInsert is used by simple string concatenations.

```
try {
        // The file reads text files 
        FileReader file = new FileReader(fileName);

        // Wrap file in BufferedReader
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(file);
        List<String> headers;
        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        if( line !=null ) { //got the row header
             headers = parseLine(line);
        }
        List<String> rowData;
        while ( (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
            rowData = parseLine(line);
            createInsert(headers, rowData);
        }
        // Close files
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch ( FileNotFoundException ex ) {
        System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'");
    } catch ( IOException ex ) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you please explain more about String tokenization and createInsert? I am not familiar with those two terms.

Answer (score 0):

Find below a working snippet with explanation of the several steps

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // read all lines into a list of strings
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("data.txt"),
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    // use the first string to generate the INSERT statement
    // without the values
    String insertLine = createInsertLine(lines.get(0));
    try (BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("data.sql"),
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        bw.write(insertLine);
        bw.write(System.lineSeparator());
        int lastValueId = lines.size() - 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= lastValueId; i++) {
            // create from each following line the VALUES part
            // of the INSERT statement
            String valueLine = createValueLine(i, lines.get(i));
            // write the lines into the file
            bw.write(valueLine);
            bw.write(i == lastValueId ? ';' : ',');
            bw.write(System.lineSeparator());
        }
    }
}

private static String createValueLine(int id, String line) {
    // split the values in the line on the '|' character
    // including leading and trailing blanks
    String[] columns = line.split(" *\\| *");
    // construct the VALUES line
    StringBuilder valueLine = new StringBuilder();
    // start with the ID value
    valueLine.append("(").append(id).append(", ");
    // append all column values, except for the last column
    for (int i = 0; i < columns.length - 1; i++) {
        valueLine.append('\'')
                .append(columns[i])
                .append("', ");
    }
    // append the last column value and the end of the line
    valueLine.append('\'')
            .append(columns[columns.length - 1])
            .append("')");
    return valueLine.toString();
}

private static String createInsertLine(String line) {
    String[] columns = line.split(" *\\| *");
    StringBuilder insertLine = new StringBuilder();
    insertLine.append("INSERT INTO 'events' ('id', ");
    for (int i = 0; i < columns.length - 1; i++) {
        insertLine.append('\'')
                .append(columns[i])
                .append("', ");
    }
    insertLine.append('\'')
            .append(columns[columns.length - 1])
            .append("') VALUES");
    return insertLine.toString();
}
```

assuming the file `data.txt` contains

```
Selected    |   Status  |   Event   |   File
Yes |   Listed  |   Birthday   | bday.pdf
No |   Not Listed  |   Gifts   | gifts.pdf
```

the generated `data.sql` will be

```
INSERT INTO 'events' ('id', 'Selected', 'Status', 'Event', 'File') VALUES
(1, 'Yes', 'Listed', 'Birthday', 'bday.pdf'),
(2, 'No', 'Not Listed', 'Gifts', 'gifts.pdf');
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked really well for me. But I am trying to do like `(1, 'Yes', 'Listed', 'Birthday', 'bday.pdf'),` instead of `(1, 'Yes', 'Listed', 'Birthday', 'bday.pdf');` And also `INSERT INTO 'events' ('id', 'Selected', 'Status', 'Event', 'File') VALUES` should only display once as the header. How can I fix those? Thanks again!

Comment: @MichaelNg **1)** Change in `createValueLine` the `.append("');");` in `.append("'),");` **2)** Move the line `bw.write(insertLine);` in the `main` method just before the `for int i = 1...`.

Comment: you did answer me the second part, thanks so much! But for the 1st question, I am trying to do like only the last line has `;` at the end, it should look like `INSERT INTO 'events' ('id', 'Selected', 'Status', 'Event', 'File') VALUES (1, 'Yes', 'Listed', 'Birthday', 'bday.pdf'),

(2, 'No', 'Not Listed', 'Gifts', 'gifts.pdf');`

Comment: Finally, it worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @MichaelNg If this solves your question, please accept this answer.